# Padding character in $format of sprintf and printf.

Tags: php

Quick question,the following code:

> echo sprintf("%'n04d", 123);

will output 0123. So the PHP will just ignore the n character if there is a 0 follow it,right? The manual page has no note about this and it has bothered me for a day. Thank you for your help!

Comment: It will not ignore, just that it will try to complete the length to 4 by left padding your number with zeroes

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But then where the n go? I mean if the code is echo sprintf("%'n4d", 123); (without the 0),output will be n123. The n was ignored because of the presentation of the 0 following it,right?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like that you want to have an alternate pad `n` instead of `0`

```
echo sprintf("%'n04d", 123);
```

If you want to have n, just use

```
echo sprintf("%'n4d", 123);
```

Comment: Thank you! I just wonder about that behaviour of ignoring the n(or any character) if a 0 is following it. And PHP just have no note on this.

Comment: ahh i see... yeah also wondered about that one.. hope someone can gave a clear info that.. :D

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is a code smell.  It should only ever be `printf()`.